# Trying to add a CHECK constraint using DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: constraints, db-browser-sqlite

Using DB Browser for SQLite I am trying to add a check constraint on a numeric field.  In the Edit Table Definition screen, I can add and name the constraint, but I'm unable to add the check conditions in the CHECK() section of the command.  I can copy the SQL to the SQL Editor window and add the check conditions there.  Is there a way to enter the check conditions on the Edit Table Definition screen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to double click into the Check field then type your constraint.
When you single click (as I have) it will give the illusion that it's not editable.
Harder clicking works :)
[Double Clicking into Check field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9usv9.png)

Comment: That works for me.  I was trying to do this on the Constraints tab instead of the Fields tab, which is another reason it wasn't working.  I love DB Browser, but it does have some quirks. Thanks for answer the question after someone down-voted it.  You restored my faith in Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I think the OP is asking about adding a CHECK constraint on the table rather than a specific column.